# Displaying views in Node.js/Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am following the peepcode (part 1) video tutorial on node.js, and I am getting stuck on the first few steps. When I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/login`, I get the following error:

*500 Error: Failed to lookup view "/Users/dantang/Desktop/Programming/Node/basic server/hotpie/apps/authentication/views/login"*

I'm guessing it is due to a typo, but I've tried changing the code several times and I can't figure out what is wrong. Would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what should I do? Thank you!

The github repo is https://github.com/tangbj/nodejs

Server.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

require("coffee-script");

var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});


//Routes
require('./apps/authentication/routes')(app);


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

login.jade

```
form(action='/sessions', method='post')
  label
    | Username
    input(type='text', name='user')
  label
    | Password
    input(type='password', name='password')
  input(type='submit', name='Submit')
```

routes.coffee

```
routes = (app) ->

  app.get '/login', (req, res) ->
    res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
      title: 'Login'
      stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.0",
    "jade": "*",
    "coffee-script": "~1.6.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I cloned your github repo and the code is working fine. Tested on Windows 7 with node v0.8.19 and express 3.1.0

Comment: Thank you. I guess it must be because I'm using a mac then. I'm using node v0.10, express 3.1.0

Comment: I will try the code tonight on my mac if you haven't found a solution by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wrong with your `login.jade` file. Maybe some encoding problem. I created a `newLogin.jade` file, changed the `render` function and everything works fine. See the pull request at [github](https://github.com/zeMirco/nodejs/commit/685f443a15b17e11713ecc1cceb4839ae21268da).

Answer (score 0):

It will be unable to find the path if you are using Windows which requires backslash instead of forward-slash in linux. So use `path.join` or `path.normalize` to get correct paths.
Try to change this in your `routes.coffee`

```
    res.render "#{__dirname}/views/login",
```

to

```
    res.render path.join(__dirname, "/views/login"),
```

and

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

to

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '../views'));
```

Otherwise verify the location of the directories/files.

Comment: Does `res.send` oftentimes used for ajax? `res.render` is used to render a view page with parameters passing to view. Is it possible to use `res.send` instead of `res.render`? When I used `res.send` it gives me blank page with only the json string in it, no styles etc are in page. Can you please differentiate between `send` and `render` method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Mac, and when I tried this, I still get the error. When I went to "file:///Users/dantang/Desktop/Programming/Node/basic%20server/hotpie/apps/authentication/views/", I see the "login.jade" file, although when I type "Users/dantang/Desktop/Programming/Node/basic server/hotpie/apps/authentication/views/login", it is an error. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @JustinJohn res.render renders a view from html and sends it but res.send sends a simple response (response code and an object) it does not render html/jade automatically, you must generate the view yourself and then put it res.send()

Comment: Never used mac, but can you check if folder is "basic%20server" or "basic folder"

Comment: I changed the name to basic_folder, but the error is still the same?